# facebook connect for Phonegap Build - cli-5.2.0 not working

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, npm

When i try to upload the APK file to the build service it gives me a error but when i remove the Facebook connect plugin it works fine so i assume its the plugin. It was working fine on older versions but i have just upgraded to the latest phonegap version cli-5.2.0

error message -

> Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build
>   server

Is this the correct plugin URL for Facebook-connect

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebookconnect-orlando" version="0.11.0" source="npm">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="####" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="####" />
</gap:plugin>
```

Comment: What is the error message ? Please edit question.

Comment: I get exactly the same message using the same PGB version and FB Connect plugin

Comment: Error message in Log: [dependency] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
...

BUILD FAILED
/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:573: Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

So, in my particular case, there appears to be a clash between the local notifications 0.8.1 plugin and facebook connect 0.9.  Removing the notifications plugin fixed the problem.

If this isn't the solution to your issue though, I'd recommend systematically removing plugins from the config.xml and uploading to identify which one is causing the problem.  Then of course notifying the plugin creator to see if they can update it.